# G Suite Admin SDK Directory API Example - "Error: Bad Request"

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-workspace

I am following the example at [Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/nodejs) and when I run it I get the error

> "The API returned an error: Error: Bad Request".

This is generated from listUsers(auth). Since the error is so ambiguous I am not sure how to troubleshoot.

```
function listUsers(auth) {
    var service = google.admin('directory_v1');
    service.users.list({
        auth: auth,
        customer: 'my_customer',
        maxResults: 10,
        orderBy: 'email'
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        var users = response.users;
        if (users.length == 0) {
            console.log('No users in the domain.');
        } else {
            console.log('Users:');
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                console.log('%s (%s)', user.primaryEmail, user.name.fullName);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: please edit your question and include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I added a code example. Hows this?